# How can I create folder and download remote images in that folder Using cron job

Tags: cron, file-permissions, mkdir

I am new to cron and I need all of your help , when I am using cron job to create folder and download images in that folder cron page giving me error that :

```
PHP Warning:  imagejpeg(): Unable to open '././../uploads/lmf-classifieds-pk/folder2/2013-04-05/36258/1365138829_498747097_3-Khyber-1990-Urgent-sale-Islamabad.jpg' for writing: No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/cron_lmf/function.php on line 143
PHP Notice:  Undefined offset: 1 in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/cron_lmf/olx_extract.php on line 562
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/cron_lmf/function.php on line 61
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/cron_lmf/function.php on line 65
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): Permission denied in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/cron_lmf/function.php on line 69
PHP Warning:  mkdir(): No such file or directory in /var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/cron_lmf/function.php on line 90
```

From these error .. I can understand cron job (page) is unable to create folder as well as download image .... Because of permission...

What should I need to do in this can ?

Please help me.

Comment: do you have complete acess ? if not change the access to the directory

Comment: I have complete directory access and now i am using path like this ...

Comment: sorry msg was not completed
var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/uploads/

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your script doesn't have the necessary permissions to do a mkdir on that folder,
check that you have write access.

Comment: I think for this i need to make folder permission 777 that i did if there is some thing other need to do ? please help me (guide me ) for that.

Comment: Do you give your imagejpeg the right path then? Do you use `dirname(__FILE__)` to get the path of the current script and then move onto `../../uploads` etc. ?

Comment: I don't think this is exactly the problem but make sure you have +x set on all the directories upto the final directory. I'm mainly saying this because of the last warning.

Comment: I am using now complete path like this :
var/www/vhosts/ip-50-62-136-81.ip.secureserver.net/lmf_this/uploads/
and still problem ... when i am accessing folder by browser it created folder but when i am using via cron its not going to create folder ,,,,

Comment: Perhaps your cron user doesn't have permission either, check this out, it might be of help.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10831785/permission-denied-mkdir-for-cron-and-browser